# how to get job counters with sqoop 1.4.4 java api?

Tags: sqoop

I'm using Sqoop 1.4.4 and its java api to run an import job and I'm having
trouble figuring out how to access the job counters once the import has
completed. I see suitable methods in the ConfigurationHelper class, like
getNumMapOutputRecords, but I'm not sure how to pass the job to them.

Is there a way to get at the job from the SqoopTool or Sqoop objects?

My code looks something like this:

```
SqoopTool sqoopTool = new ImportTool();

SqoopOptions options = new SqoopOptions();

options.setConnectString(connectString);
options.setUsername(username);
options.setPassword(password);
options.setTableName(table);
options.setColumns(columns);
options.setWhereClause(whereClause);
options.setTargetDir(targetDir);
options.setNumMappers(1);
options.setFileLayout(FileLayout.TextFile);
options.setFieldsTerminatedBy(delimiter);

Configuration config = new Configuration();

config.set("oracle.sessionTimeZone", timezone.getID());

System.setProperty(Sqoop.SQOOP_RETHROW_PROPERTY, "1");

Sqoop sqoop = new Sqoop(sqoopTool, config, options);

String[] nullArgs = new String[0];

Sqoop.runSqoop(sqoop, nullArgs);
```